# How to convert variable's address to string variable in C?

Tags: c, string, pointers

How to store address string to a `char *`variable or `char` array?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int number = 1200;
    printf("Address = %p\n", &number);
    // char address[30];

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [snprintf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf)

Comment: @kaylum I see. I didn't realize I can use this function to do this. Thank you!!

Comment: Pedantically, should be `printf("Address = %p\n", (void*) &number);` as `"%p"` matches `void *`, not certainly `int *`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way of doing it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int number = 1200;
    size_t n = 0;
    int n2;
    char *s = NULL;
retry:
    n2 = snprintf(s, n, "Address = %p", &number);
    if(n2 <= 0) {
        printf("snprintf failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if(!n) {
        n = n2 + 1;
        s = malloc(n);
        if(!s) {
            printf("malloc failed\n");
            return 1;
        }
        goto retry;
    }
    printf("%s\n", s);
    free(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Here's a goto-less version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int number = 1200;
    char *s = NULL;
    size_t n = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        int n2 = snprintf(s, n, "Address = %p", &number);
        if(n2 <= 0) {
            printf("snprintf failed\n");
            return 1;
        }
        if(n)
            break;
        n = n2 + 1;
        s = malloc(n);
        if(!s) {
           printf("malloc failed\n");
           return 1;
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n", s);
    free(s);
    return 0;
}
```

and for me it prints:

```
Address = 0x7ffea89d5e6c
```

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica yes, caught me making 2 separate changes.  Already fixed.

Comment: @Cheatah yeah, already fixed.

Comment: UV for persistence! :-)

Comment: @Fe2O3 Always happy to revise.

Comment: That `snprintf` needs a cast to `void *` for the pointer. And I am not sure why you want to suggest using `goto` as a replacement for a simple loop.

Comment: @Gerhardth Why do you think the (void *) cast is required?  How to do I convince gcc to generate a warning for this?  goto seemed the most direct code to me.  The loop version is indented more but `n2` is now a local variable as it's clearer that it should only run twice.  If you had something more streamlined in mind for a "simple loop" please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

To convert variable's address to string, use `snprintf()` with `"%p"` and cast the object address to `void *`.

Cast conforms to the C spec.

> p
> The argument shall be a pointer to `void`. The value of the pointer is converted to a sequence of printing characters, in an implementation-defined manner.

The only tricky bits remaining are determining a reasonable size and managing the buffer.

---

I like a single call to `snprintf()` with a generous buffer scaled to a reasonable worst case size.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define PTR_FMT "Address = %p\n"
// How about allowing a charter per pointer bit and a "0x"` to handle %p "implementation-defined manner".
#define PERCENT_P_FMT_SIZE (sizeof(void *) * CHAR_BIT + 3)

int main(void) {
    int number = 1200;

    char buf[sizeof PTR_FMT + PERCENT_P_FMT_SIZE];
    int len = snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, PTR_FMT, (void *) &number);
    assert(len > 0 && (unsigned) len < sizeof buf); 
    fputs(buf, stdout);
}
```

Comment: The resulting string would have an embedded preamble and LF. Is this what was wanted??? Slow day... `:-)`

Comment: @Fe2O3 This answer follows OP's sample `"Address = %p\n"` format.  What is nice about it is that it scales well the buffer size should a code update change the preamble and trailing text in `#define PTR_FMT "Address = %p\n"`, be it `"%p"` or large.

Comment: PERCENT_P_FMT_SIZE has one too many `(`

Comment: PERCENT_P_FMT_SIZE is 64 for me on a 64 bit system.  What about `#define PERCENT_P_FMT_SIZE (sizeof("0x") - 1 + 2 * sizeof(void *))` which is 18 bytes?  Is the `%p` format standardized?  Clearly one-shot is the better way than what I suggested.

Comment: @AllanWind It is "implementation-defined manner", post amended to reflect that.  IMO, if a "right-size" allocation is desired, sprint to a generous buffer, perhaps even 2x expected size and then `strdup()` the fixed buffer.  Or the double call as you suggest - 6.001 - half-a-dozen of the other.

Comment: @AllanWind Hyper-pedantic code worries about the 2nd `sprintf()` call being larger than the first due to a _locale_ change due to some parallel thread or phase of the moon.  Such concerns are a bear to test.  IMO - use the code that is 1) explainable, 2) portably correct and 3) testable.

Comment: @AllanWind `#define PERCENT_P_FMT_SIZE (sizeof("0x") - 1 + 2 * sizeof(void *))` certainly reasonable - when `CHAR_BIT` is 8 and the hex notation lacks additional punctuation marks.  For me, I see little advantage of a tight _initial_ buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your sample (using a local character buffer)...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int number = 1200;

    printf( "Address = %p\n", &number );

    char buf[30]; // generous enough?
    sprintf( buf, "%p", &number );

    printf( "Address = %s\n", buf );

    return 0;
}
```